# Error: redirect count exceeded with many fetch and Promise.all() in a Firebase callable function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise

When I'm doing this inside a firebase callable function:

```js
    for (const origin of originList) {
      for (const destiny of destinyList) {
        // mount the url

        const respPromise = fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          // manipulate a big JSON (2000 lines or more each one)
        })

        fetchPromises.push(respPromise)
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(fetchPromises)
```

Both list can have more the 10 registers, so the fetch will run hundreds of time.
It's very unstable, sometimes I get the right result, but most of time I get:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: fetch failed
...
cause: Error: redirect count exceeded
      at makeNetworkError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4801:35)
      at httpRedirectFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9659:16)
      at httpFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9632:28)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async schemeFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9535:18)
      at async node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9409:20
      at async mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9399:20)
      at async httpFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9632:22)
      at async schemeFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9535:18)
      at async node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9409:20
```

I don't know if it's a pure javascript code and I can fi but refactoring the code or firebase can't call so many fetch's inside a callable function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like a problem with your URL, not your code.  Something about the URL is redirecting to another URL too many times.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't think so. The same URL is highly tested on others environments. I never have an error with postman or cURL. Or when this fetch were directly on my React code. This error only happened when I transfer the code from ReactJS to this firebase Callable  function.

Comment: We'll not know for sure without the full details anyone can use to reproduce the issue exactly as you see it. Everything in your error stack trace is pointing to a problem observed withing the nodejs runtime and not in your code, so one imagines that the problem is with something you provided to node's implementation of fetch (the URL).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my coding calling the Firebase Function.

I was instantiating the Firebase callable function inside the `handleSubmit()` function in the frontend.

When I transfer it to outside, the error has stooped:

```js
  import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions'

  const functions = getFunctions()
  const callableReturnMessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'myFunction')
```